# My Ruby array is sorted non-deterministicly

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

When I sort this array, it keeps returning different sort orders.

```
a = [ [0, 'cow'], [0, 'chicken'], [0, 'cat'], [0, 'goat'], [0, 'sheep'], [0, 'pig']]
a.push [1, 'dog']

a.sort_by! { |s| s[0] }
# => [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
a.sort_by! { |s| s[0] }
# => [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "goat"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "pig"], [1, "dog"]]
a.sort_by! { |s| s[0] }
# => [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
a.sort_by! { |s| s[0] }
# => [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "goat"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "pig"], [1, "dog"]]
a.sort_by! { |s| s[0] }
```

Why am I getting different sort orders?

Comment: So what? Help in what way? By the way, it is not polite to order people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do two `sort_by!` followed by each other, you should be aware that you're not feeding the same input to the first method as the second methods since `sort_by!` is modifying `a` before you feed it into the second `sort_by!`

```
a = [ [0, 'cow'], [0, 'chicken'], [0, 'cat'], [0, 'goat'], [0, 'sheep'], [0, 'pig'], [1, 'dog']]

a.sort_by! { |s| s[0] }

=> [[0, "cow"],
 [0, "chicken"],
 [0, "cat"],
 [0, "pig"],
 [0, "sheep"],
 [0, "goat"],
 [1, "dog"]]
```

`a` becomes this last array. Now when you sort the second time, you're feeding a different input.

Now, in order to confirm that the algorithm is deterministic, do this:

```
sorted = []; 100.times { a = [ [0, 'cow'], [0, 'chicken'], [0, 'cat'], [0, 'goat'], [0, 'sheep'], [0, 'pig'], [1, 'dog']]; sorted << a.sort_by! { |s| s[0] } }

sorted.uniq.count
=> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby uses Quicksort, which is an unstable sorting algorithm. This means that the order of equal elements may change after the array is sorted.

Now if you use `sort_by` instead of the mutator method `sort_by!`, the array you started with will not be altered. Therefore, `sort_by` will yield the same result every time.

When you use `sort_by!`, the original array is replaced with the sorted one and thus the elements may change their order after each iteration. This means the output isn't nondeterministic, it just depends on the input.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense unless `sort_by!` is modifying the array in place during the sort.

Comment: @Chloe indeed `sort_by!` is modifying the array in place, just as any other mutator method. These are mostly denoted by an exclamation mark at the end of the method name, unless it is clear that the method changes the state of the object. `Array#pop` for example has no exclamation mark, because the operation would not make sense without modifying the original array.

Answer (score -1):

Use `a = a.sort_by` instead. `#sort_by!` appears to be non-deterministic.

```
irb(main):132:0> a.sort_by { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
irb(main):133:0> a.sort_by { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
irb(main):134:0> a.sort_by { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
irb(main):135:0> a.sort_by { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
irb(main):136:0> a.sort_by { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
irb(main):137:0> a.sort_by { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
irb(main):138:0> a.sort_by { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
irb(main):139:0> a.sort_by { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
irb(main):140:0> a.sort_by { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
irb(main):141:0> a.sort_by { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
irb(main):142:0> a.sort_by! { |s| s[0] }
=> [[0, "cow"], [0, "chicken"], [0, "cat"], [0, "pig"], [0, "sheep"], [0, "goat"], [1, "dog"]]
```

Comment: It is the same sorting algorithm in both cases. It *is* deterministic, but does not preserve original order for equal elements. The difference is that repeatedly calling `sort_by!` is changing the input, creating a feedback loop.